# PHP / MySql if statement returning null when should be set

Tags: php, mysql

Relatively new to PHP and SQL, have tried researching a fix but have thus far been unsuccessful. The site I am trying to develop is an online CV for a school assignment.

I am trying to create CRUD pages to dynamically create, read, update and delete records from my database. Essentially what my problem is, is that my if statement does not seem to be able to recognize my database rows by their id (edu_ID in the example below). This results in edu_ID being null and being redirected back to useradmin.php

This problem occurs when trying to navigate to the read/update pages from the main user admin page. Code for the table as is displayed on the user admin page is as follows:

```
    <?php   
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
      echo '<tr class="database">';
      echo '<td class="database"><p>'. $row['dates'] . '</p></td>';
      echo '<td class="database"><p>'. $row['institution'] . '</p></td>';
      echo '<td class="database"><p>'. $row['qualification'] . '</p></td>';
      echo '<td class="database truncate"><p>'. $row['description'] . '</p></td>';
      echo '<td class="database"><p>';
      echo '<button class="crud"><a href="eduread.php?id='.$row['edu_ID'].'">Read</a></button>';
      echo '<button class="crud"><a href="eduupdate.php?id='.$row['edu_ID'].'">Update</a></button>';
      echo '<button class="crud"><a href="edudelete.php?id='.$row['edu_ID'].'">Delete</a></button>';
      echo '</p></td>';
      echo '</tr>';
      }
       Database::disconnect();
      ?>
```

The problem does not appear to be with the database connection, as I am able to successfully create pages and load data from the database in other areas of my site.

Code below is for the read page:

```
<?php
require 'includes/connect.php';

$edu_ID = null; 

if ( !empty($_GET['edu_ID'])) {
    $edu_ID = $_REQUEST['edu_ID'];
}

if ( $edu_ID == null) {
    echo 'not set';
    header("Location: useradmin.php");
 } else {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM education WHERE edu_ID = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($edu_ID));
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
?>
```

This is the code I am trying to display this data with, but this does not appear to be where the problem lies:

```
<table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>dates</th>
        <th>instituation</th>
        <th>qualification</th>
        <th>description</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    <?php
      echo '<tr class="database">';
      echo '<td class="database"><p>'. $data['dates'] . '</p></td>';
      echo '<td class="database"><p>'. $data['institution'] . '</p></td>';
      echo '<td class="database"><p>'. $data['qualification'] . '</p></td>';
      echo '<td class="database"><p>'. $data['description'] . '</p></td>';
      echo '</tr>';
      ?>
      </tbody>
      </table>
```

have also linked my [database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEfOX.jpg)

In case it is relevant, here is a link to the tutorial I was using to try set up my pages http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/php-crud-tutorial-part-2
(I have chosen to display my data slightly differently as I am not using bootstrap as they have in this tutorial, although I have also tried using bootstrap, purely so I could mimic the tutorial exactly and encountered the same issues.)

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the SQL query used in the `$pdo->query($sql) as $row` code?  What does `var_dump($row);` show you?

Comment: Should have included above, the query used for $pdo->query($sql) as $row is $pdo = Database::connect(); $sql = 'SELECT * FROM education ORDER BY edu_ID DESC'; . var_dump($row); displays all the data from my rows as an arrays

Comment: Seems as though it should, but the var_dump shows that each row has a valid value for `$row['edu_ID']`?  Oh, actually I see your problem now...you have `if ( !empty($_GET['edu_ID'])) {
    $edu_ID = $_REQUEST['edu_ID'];` in your read page, but you are linking to it using `id` as the URL parameter.  Change it to look for `$_REQUEST['id']` or change the HTML output to use `edu_ID` instead of `id`.

Comment: thank you, that fixed my problem :)

Comment: Glad that helped, good luck!